# Erroneous Value returned, Any Ideas?

Tags: c++, c++11, version

I have a problem that seems to be a C++ version issue but not a sufficient background to choose vocabulary and labels necessary to lookup or identify my issue.

I have to compile my application on a school server using C++11, but I edit on Replit:

```sh
clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main Car.cpp CarWash.cpp main.cpp
```

I run the application on Replit and all values come out fine.

I run the application on the school server and there are incorrect values that occur at specific places in the data processing. So I examined the data. (It is just a text file with a number, newline, number, newline, etc.)

When I call an int return method on a class using a pointer with an arrow operator, only 2 out of 100 values are incorrect. If the int return method should return a small value  0-10 range (but not consistently) I get 281 and then later 47. I tried some casting options to see if that was the issue and also verified the object's values were not strange.

The culprit I think is the math function in `car->getWait();` (a simple subtraction problem)

The method is written as:

```cpp
int Car::getWait() 
{ 
  return washStart - timeArrived;
}
```

I even made other return methods and vars so I could return washStart and `timeArrived` separately to perform the operation, then use `cout` to display. I get the same specifically large wrong number at specific places while the rest of the operations work fine.

Replit Output:

|  | Returned |
| --- | --- |
| 41 | 0.000000 |
| 42 | 2.000000 |
| 43 | 4.000000 |
|  |  |
| 83 | 2.000000 |
| 84 | 0.000000 |
| 85 | 1.000000 |

Server Output:

|  | Returned |
| --- | --- |
| 41 | 0.000000 |
| 42 | 281.000000 |
| 43 | 4.000000 |
|  |  |
| 83 | 2.000000 |
| 84 | 37.000000 |
| 85 | 1.000000 |

[Car.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwiBY.png)

[Car.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJDDX.png)

Comment: Don't send a picture of your code, Copy & Paste a minimal reproducible of your problem.

Comment: Please do not post code as images. It should be included in your question as text.